# Module structure on $R$-algebra $S$ by restriction of scalars and splitting of the algebra map

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, functors, algebras

Let $R, S$ be commutative Noetherian rings. Let $f: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Consider the $R$-module $f_* S$ whose underlying abelian group is $S$ itself but the $R$-module structure is given by $r\cdot s:= f(r)s, \forall r \in R, s \in f_*S$. With this module structure, note that $f: R\to f_*S$ is an $R$-linear map.

Now assume $f_*S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. If $R$ is a direct summand of $f_*S$ as $R$-modules, then does the $R$-linear map $f: R\to f_*S$ split as a morphism of $R$-modules ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Note that $f_\ast S$ can be regarded as $R\otimes_RS$, with $f:R\to R\otimes_RS$ given by $f(r)=r\otimes1$.

The map $g:S\to S\otimes_RS$ given by $g(s)=s\otimes1$ is a split $R$-module monomorphism, with splitting map the multiplication map $m:S\otimes_RS\to S$ given by $m(s\otimes s')=ss'$.

Suppose $S=R\oplus X$ as $R$-modules. So $g$ is the direct sum of the map $f:R\to R\otimes_R S$ and a map $h:X\to X\otimes_RS$ given by $h(x)=x\otimes1$.

Then $\pi\circ m:R\otimes_RS\to R$, where $\pi:R\oplus X\to R$ is projection onto the direct factor, is a splitting map for $f$.

Comment: Thank you ... This turned out to be a little more intricate than I thought ... do you think we could weaken the hypothesis to just require "$R$ is a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $f_*S$" ? If $R$ is local, then $R| M^{\oplus n}$ implies $R|M$ , but if $R$ is Not local, then at least is this algebra case special enough to conclude the same?

Comment: @uno Yes. In fact, the same proof shows that if $M$ is an $R$-module, then the natural $R$-module homomorphism $M\to M\otimes_RS$ is a split monomorphism if and only if $M$ is a direct summand of $f_\ast N$ for some $S$-module $N$.

Comment: @uno A more general fact is that if $L:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ and $R:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}$ are an adjoint pair of additive functors between additive categories, then for an object $M$ of $\mathcal{A}$, the unit map $M\to RLM$ is a split monomorphism if and only if $M$ is a direct summand of $RN$ for some object $N$ of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the more general statements... do you know if something similar is also true for Noetherian separated schemes or not? Namely, let $f: Y \to X$ be a proper birational morphism of Noetherian separated schemes. Assume $\mathcal O_X$ is a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $Rf_* \mathcal O_Y$; then is it true that the natural map $\mathcal O_X \to Rf_* \mathcal O_Y$ is split?

Comment: @uno Yes. In fact, for any map of schemes $f:X\to Y$, $f^\ast:D^+(QCoh Y)\to D^+(QCoh X)$ and $Rf_\ast:D^+(QCoh X)\to D^+(QCoh Y)$ are adjoint functors with $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$, so this follows from the adjoint functor fact.

Comment: @uno ($f_\ast\mathcal{O}_Y$ should be $f^\ast\mathcal{O}_Y$ in my last comment.)

Comment: This is very awesome ! Do you have a reference for the general fact about additive categories that you mentioned?

Comment: @uno I don’t offhand know a reference for the general statement, but the main input is that if $L$, $R$ are an adjoint pair of functors with unit $\eta$ and counit $\varepsilon$ then the composition $R\xrightarrow{\eta R}RLR\xrightarrow{R\varepsilon}R$ is the identity (so for additive functors between additive categories, $R$ is a direct summand of $RLR$). You’ll find this in most introductory books on category theory. For example, it’s Theorem 1 on  page 82 of Mac Lane’s *Categories for the Working Mathematician*. From there, the proof proceeds exactly as in my answer.

Comment: @uno Actually, maybe I need more than additive categories (abelian would do) to ensure that $R$ has a complement in $RLR$.

Comment: @uno By the way, another place this (or the dual statement) comes up is in the definition of relatively projective modules. If $R\subseteq S$ are rings, two of the standard equivalent definitions for an $S$-module $M$ to be relatively $R$-projective are “$M$ is a direct summand of $N\otimes_RS$ for some $R$-module $N$” and “the natural $S$-module homomorphism $M\otimes_RS\to M$ is a split epimorphism”.

Comment: Here's what my true motivations are behind asking for the scheme case; namely if it is true that for any proper birational map of Noetherian schemes $f:X \to Y$, $\mathcal O_Y $ being a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies $R f_* \mathcal O_X$ implies that the natural map $\mathcal O_Y \to Rf_* \mathcal O_X$ splits, then we would have the following: Let $Y$ be a normal variety of characteristic $0$. If for some resolution of singularities $f: X \to Y$ it holds that $\mathcal O_Y \in \langle Rf_* \mathcal O_X \rangle_1$ in $D(Coh(Y))$, then $Y$ has rational singularities.

Comment: (...continued from previous comment...) actually I also need to assume $Coh(Y)$ is a Krull-Schmidt category. Proof: Since the indecomposable direct summands of $Rf_* \mathcal O_X[n]$ are the same as $Rf_* \mathcal O_X$ upto shift and multiplicity, hence $\mathcal O_Y \in \langle Rf_* \mathcal O_X \rangle_1$ implies $\mathcal O_Y$ is a direct summand of a finite direct sum of copies of $R f_* \mathcal O_X$. Now by the claim I sought (for which you possibly have a proof Jeremy) implies that the natural map $\mathcal O_Y \to Rf_* \mathcal O_X$ splits. (...to be continued in next comment...)

Comment: (...continued from previous comment...) Now we can deduce $Y$ has rational singularities by the first direction of the proof of Theorem 2.12 of https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X12000309

Comment: did you see my subsequent comments? Do you think it holds for the scheme case?

Comment: @uno Yes. Isn't it just an application of the general fact about adjoint functors that I mentioned? Or am I missing something?

Comment: But $D(Coh X)$ is not abelian though ... (also, what do I replace tensor-product in your proof by?)

Comment: @uno Ah, I see what you mean. But a triangulated category will do. If $(L,R)$ is an adjoint pair, then the natural map $R\to RLR$ is split without any assumptions on the categories. But more is need for a split monomorphism to be the inclusion of a direct summand. It's true in an abelian category because if $0\to X\xrightarrow{f}Y\to Z\to0$ is a short exact sequence with $f$ a split monomorphism, then $Y\cong X\oplus Z$. It's true in a triangulated category because if $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\to Z\to X[1]$ is a distinguished triangle with $f$ a split monomorphism, then $Y\cong X\oplus Z$.

Comment: @uno In the original question, the adjoint functors are $L=S\otimes_R-$ and $R=\text{restriction along }f$ (sorry that $R$ seems to be both a ring and a right adjoint functor!) In the scheme case, $L=f^\ast$ and $R=Rf_\ast$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you with this again, but I'm going through your answer again, and I am again confused by one point ... $f^*$ does not seem to be the right adjoint of $Rf_*$, at least not according to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A9D ... and this right adjoint does not seem to send the structure sheaf to structure sheaf ...

Comment: @uno I was using that $f^\ast$ is the **left** adjoint of $Rf_\ast$.